# How to get the hidden data from this webpage using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

The page I'm trying to retrieve data from is "http://pool.burstcoin.eu/", when I just cURL the url, there isn't much data returned, but there are data on page when I open this site in a browser. For example I want to retrieve the data from the table under "Historic Shares". How do I go about doing this with cURL?

```
$url = "http://pool.burstcoin.eu/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The web page loads the data using AJAX. You need something that emulates a browser running Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, any suggestions or point me in the right direction?